# Error al desplegar Strapi 4.1.9 en Heroku

Tags: heroku, strapi

estoy tratando de desplegar por primera vez un proyecto de strapi a heroku sin exito alguno, hasta ahora revolvi y recorri varios tipos de intentos de fix pero la verdad nada de nada, segui al pie de la letra la documentacion y tampoco nada de nada.

```
2022-05-09T20:15:23.305444+00:00 app[web.1]: > back-tempo@0.1.0 start
2022-05-09T20:15:23.305445+00:00 app[web.1]: > strapi start
2022-05-09T20:15:23.305445+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-05-09T20:15:28.696040+00:00 app[web.1]: (node:22) Warning: [deprecated] In future versions, Strapi will stop reading directly from the environment variable API_TOKEN_SALT. Please set apiToken.salt in config/admin.js instead.
2022-05-09T20:15:28.696068+00:00 app[web.1]: For security reasons, keep storing the secret in an environment variable and use env() to read it in config/admin.js (ex: `apiToken: { salt: env('API_TOKEN_SALT') }`). See https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/configurations/optional/environment.html#configuration-using-environment-variables.
2022-05-09T20:15:28.696069+00:00 app[web.1]: (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
2022-05-09T20:15:28.704144+00:00 app[web.1]: [2022-05-09 20:15:28.702] error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available 54.224.34.30:6506
2022-05-09T20:15:28.704146+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: listen EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available 54.224.34.30:6506
2022-05-09T20:15:28.704146+00:00 app[web.1]: at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1355:21)
2022-05-09T20:15:28.704147+00:00 app[web.1]: at listenInCluster (node:net:1420:12)
2022-05-09T20:15:28.704147+00:00 app[web.1]: at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (node:net:1559:7)
2022-05-09T20:15:28.704148+00:00 app[web.1]: at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:73:8)
2022-05-09T20:15:58.308819+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H20 desc="App boot timeout" method=GET path="/" host=tempo-back.herokuapp.com request_id=d37630f2-b854-49aa-b1bd-f2388b2e5fd8 fwd="186.13.11.73" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-05-09T20:16:20.354180+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2022-05-09T20:16:20.512714+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2022-05-09T20:16:20.821587+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2022-05-09T20:16:20.888660+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-05-09T20:16:22.747987+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=tempo-back.herokuapp.com request_id=1a0e3aa3-5e19-4124-ac24-5400889733ce fwd="186.13.11.73" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-05-09T20:16:23.279107+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=tempo-back.herokuapp.com request_id=04a59a92-f46c-4079-9e73-236b41e7fdae fwd="186.13.11.73" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

La verdad acudo a ustedes por no se q mas hacer al respecto.

Comment: Jelou! Bienvenidx a SOes. Acá el idioma a usar es español, así que es necesario que vayas a [edit] y traduzcas tooooooooda la pregunta, por favor (el log no, todo lo demás sí) :)

Answer (score 0):

Suena [segun ve uno por ahí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62046675/heroku-returns-error-listen-eaddrnotavail-address-not-available-on-starting) a que es necesario que uses como host `0.0.0.0` por líos en el enrutamiento interno, que hace que intente usar un host que no está disponible.

Comment: me devuelve el mismo error.